# Redis replication uses options of redis snapshotting

Tags: redis

There are some configuration related to snapshotting in redis docs

> rdbcompression yes
>   rdbchecksum yes

As while master-slave replication, both diskless and disk-based, also rdb file is created (Source - https://redis.io/topics/replication).

Are the above options also plays part in replication i.e. rdb file which is created while replication is being compressed ??

Comment: AFAIK, YES, these options take part in replication.

Comment: I think you are right, I have tested for same with disk-based replication and verified the rdb size, but disk-less I am still not sure.